# SIM is unsupported on Galaxy Y running CM11

Tags: cyanogenmod, sim-card, samsung-galaxy-y

There's a problem with my Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 after upgrading from GingerBread to Android KitKat.

I followed all the steps starting from downloading CWM, CyanogenMod 11, and the KitKat ROM. And thankfully I was successful. At first, it was so long before the update was fully installed on my Galaxy Y.

**Problem:** When I turn it on, it accepts the SD Card, but **SIM card is not detected**.

I tried rebooting over and over again. But only the SD card works, specifically that only the SD card is inserted, not SIM card and it works properly. But it **doesn't start when SIM card is inserted**.

Now I rebooted it with only the SIM card inserted, hoping that "somehow" my Galaxy Y will take its time rebooting while my SIM card is inserted. But still, I'm not sure what will happen. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have to do:

1. Reflash your ROM
2. After reflashing, let it boot
3. Turn off your profile and shutdown
4. Wait until the phone vibrates and open it again

If it doesn't work, format cache, system, data, and also cache on CWM recovery, then try reflashing again.

Comment: Is there any technical reason as why it is supposed to work or any reason as to why the issue occurs?